# Python - Julia variables transfering

Tags: python, environment-variables, julia, transfer

Let's say I have a jupyter notebook with both python and julia. In julia i have a variable

```
var_julia = 10
```

and in python I have

```
var_python = 20
```

What I would like to do is to efficiently (without any JSONs nor CSVs) transfer these 2 variables between, so I can print var_julia in python and var_python in julia. How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically using the forementioned PyCall PyJulia you can do:

```
var_python = 10

%%julia
py"var_python"
```

and for the other way round:

```
var_julia = 20

new_var = %julia var_julia
print(new_var)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [PythonCall and JuliaCall](https://cjdoris.github.io/PythonCall.jl/stable/) which should cover your use case.

There's also [PyCall.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl) for the "call Python from Julia" direction and [PyJulia](https://pyjulia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) for the "call Julia from Python" direction.